# Using Laravel config file data inside vue component

Tags: laravel-vue

I am developing a web app using laravel and vue . Now i want to use laravel config file data like app name inside vue component . How do i suppose to do that ?

Comment: i did this by passing config data as props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can pass config data as props to vue component.